# Losing data when transferring data from TreeMap to TreeSet.

Tags: java, treemap, treeset, sortedset

I have a TreeMap like so.

```
// Create a map of word and their counts.
// Put them in TreeMap so that they are naturally sorted by the words
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
wordCount.put("but", 100);
wordCount.put("all", 10);
```

Since it is a TreeMap the content are sorted by key, i.e. the words.

```
    // Iterate over the map to confirm that the data is stored sorted by words.
    // This part is also working nicely and I can see that the ouput is sorted by
    // words.
    Set<String> words = wordCount.keySet();
    logger.debug("word, count");
    for (Iterator<String> itForWords = words.iterator(); itForWords.hasNext();) {
        String word = (String) itForWords.next();
        Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
        logger.debug("{}, {}", word, count);
    }
```

Now I am trying to sort them by count. Since TreeMap will not drop the trick I am moving them to a SortedSet.

```
    // Trying to sort the collection by the count now.
    // TreeMap cant be sorted on values.
    // Lets put them in a sorted set and put a comparator to sort based on values
    // rather than keys.
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordCountSortedByCount = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
                }

            });
    wordCountSortedByCount.addAll(wordCount.entrySet());
```

At this point I am expecting the TreeSet to have 2 entries. But it is showing only one. Please help.

```
    // This is NOT WORKING
    // The size is only 1. It should have been two.
    logger.debug("Size of sorted collection is {}", wordCountSortedByCount.size());
```

Comment: `return o1.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());` surely you mean `return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());` ?

Comment: what is your question? are you trying to sort the map by their value(count) ?

Comment: Yup. Silly me. I made a typo. Also, I found out from @dehasi that I could actually use much smaller construct, since I was going to use the natural ordering of Integers which is the value in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid such errors, it worth to use comparator in Java 8:

```
Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)


SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordCountSortedByCount = 
new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify `return o1.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue())`; to
`return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());`

Output will be 2.